# Align Bootstrap table sticky headers with columns when scrolling

Tags: 7, bootstrap-theme

I'm using Bootstrap theme in my Drupal 7 site.

In a custom module, I create a simple table (not views) and the headers are aligned with the corresponding columns:

[image]

When I scroll down the headers become misaligned:

[image]

Is this a consequence of the responsive theme? I need the header to be always aligned no matter the size of the browser window. What do I need to change in my theme (or code) to achieve that?

Comment: Hey hey, questions like that are difficult to debug from afar. We'd actually need a reproducible problem. Which we don't have here, since we don't know your code, your settings, your styles, your markup, your server etc. – therefore debugging always needs to be done by you.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking that, as I am using Boostrap theme 7.x-3.23 with no custom changes and doing a simple table using theme_table, it would be easy to understand what was needed to solve this. In fact, this behavior happens on all tables of the site (including core pages).